# Python parse webpage links counter

Tags: python, parsing, url, hyperlink, counter

I'm just parsing links from a url using the code below. The links are found however my counter does not work. any ideas on how to fix my counter please?
thanks

def parse_all_links(html):

```
links =  re.findall(r"""a href=(['"].*['"])""", html)#find links starting with href
print("found the following links addresses: ".format(len(html)))#print a message before the output

if len(links) ==0:
    print("Sorry, no links found")
else:
    count = 1#this count how many links are displayed
    for e in links:
        print(e)
        count += 1

print('--------------')
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with "my counter does not work"?

Comment: Hi, the actual links are displayed when I run the code, but I cannot see a total number of links

Comment: Did my answer resolved your issue?

Comment: Yeah thanks so much mrangry777 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand your question but there are some small problems with your code. So let me know if this helps:

```
import re
import requests
def parse_all_links(html):
    links = re.findall(r"""a href=(['"].*['"])""", html)  # find links starting with href
    print("found the following links addresses: ".format(len(html)))  # print a message before the output

    if len(links) == 0:
        print("Sorry, no links found")
    else:
        count = 0  # this count how many links are displayed
        for e in links:
            print(e)
            count += 1

    print('--------------\nCount:{}'.format(count))


parse_all_links(requests.get("http://www.onet.pl").text)
```

I tested the solution and it works. Sample output:

```
...
"https://zapytaj.onet.pl/Zadania/testy/index.html"
"https://zapytaj.onet.pl/quizy/index.html"
"https://zapytaj.onet.pl/Category/005/1,Biznes_i_Finanse.html"
"https://zapytaj.onet.pl/Category/029/1,Gry.html"
"https://zapytaj.onet.pl/Category/028/1,Hobby.html"
"https://zapytaj.onet.pl/Category/021/1,Dla_Doroslych.html"
"https://zapytaj.onet.pl/Category/009/1,Dom_i_Ogrod.html"
"https://zapytaj.onet.pl/Category/016/1,Jedzenie_i_Napoje.html"
"http://zapytaj.onet.pl"
"https://polityka-prywatnosci.onet.pl/"
"http://reklama.onet.pl/"
"http://ofirmie.onet.pl/0,0,0,PL,aktualne_ogloszenia,oferta.html"
"http://onettechnologie.pl/"
"http://www.dreamlab.pl/"
--------------
Count:319
```

Comment: In your code please make counter count=0, so that it gives you exact count of links from webpage

Comment: Thanks I dunno why I overlooked it

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the len()-function to get the length of your list of links and a dedicated parsing library like Beautiful Soup to parse the HTML, since it can handle malformed or otherwise badly formatted HTML like a champ.

```
#encoding: utf-8
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#example HTML
html = """
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Link page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a href="https://www.google.com" class="link">Google</a>
      <a href="https://www.yahoo.com" class="link">Yahoo</a>
      <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class="link">Stackoverflow</a>
    </body>
  </html>
"""

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

links = [a["href"] for a in parsed_html.find_all("a")]

if len(links) ==0:
    print("Sorry, no links found")
else:
    count = len(links)
    for e in links:
        print(e)
    #print the total amount of links
    print(count, "links in total")
print('--------------')
```

Comment: @mrangry777 I see no such things. Could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: This line `print count, "links in total"` it is python 2 syntax. It is not maybe incorrect but should be noted